# Selenium java - not able to identify the text box by xpath, css

Tags: css, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

Below is the HTML snippet of the textbox that i am trying to identify using chromdriver

Comment: <input class="FC2 ELX_UserPrompt  binding_Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff_SerialNo" autofocus="" placeholder="Scan Serial No" onchange="OperationOutputHelper.UpdateOutput(this,event,'Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff','SerialNo');" onkeyup="OperationOutputHelper.UpdateOutput(this,event,'Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff','SerialNo');" autosubmit="true" runat="server" style="cursor: auto;">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags. Also be sure to read [ask] and understand what makes a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following Xpath:

```
//input[@placeholder="Scan Serial No"]
```

ry using multiple attributes

```
//input[@placeholder="Scan Serial No"][contains(@class,'FC2 ELX_UserPrompt')]
```

Comment: Already tried and it did not worked. It says cannot identify the element WebElement validate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Scan Serial No']"));

Answer (score 0):

For getting selectors there are a few techniques I use.

First I use the built in tools of the Chrome Developer Tools. Open these with ctr+shift+i. Then locate the element you want, ctrl+shift+c then click on the element. This highlights the element you want in the Elements tab. right click on the highlighted element and choose Copy>Copy selector. This will give you a unique css selector for that item. This works well for everything except dynamic elements that have changing id's or locations on the page.

For dynamic elements I use advanced css selectors. where you can leverage the html tag in addition to any css attributes to locate the element. Here is a decent write up on how to use these https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/#comments
For you particular element you could do something like `input[placeholder='Scan Serial No']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath:

- name of class in xpath

  ```
  //input[@class='FC2 ELX_UserPrompt binding_Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff_SerialNo??']
  ```
- name of class and placeholder

  ```
  //input[@class='FC2 ELX_UserPrompt binding_Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff_SerialNo??'][@placeholder='Scan Serial No']
  ```

Comment: May be you did not notice but the class below is dynamic and not fixed . binding_Screen_cc607e87_a82b_4cac_8c38_939be2ba00ff_SerialNo